# Read files in a Task

Tags: java, javafx

I'm a beginner in Java and JavaFX.
I have a problem, I want to count PDFs in folders and i want show the 
process in a ProgressBar.

I know the quantity of the PDF's and i must check if all are there.

The method to read the folder's is:

```
private void dir(File fileRoot) {
     File[] files = fileRoot.listFiles();
     for(File file : files) {
         if(file.isDirectory()){
             dir(file);
         }    
         else{
             String dateiName = file.getName();
             if(dateiName.endsWith(".pdf")){
                 ++countPDF;
                 System.out.println(countPDF);              
             }
         }
     }
```

The method to update the ProgressBar is:

```
private Task<Boolean> createWorker() {    
    return new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {

                    updateMessage(countPDF + "");
                    updateProgress(countPDF, number);

            }
            return true;
        };
    }
```

how i can combine there in a controller?

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button startButton;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar myProzessBar;
    @FXML
    private Label label;

    private int countPDF;
    private File directory;

    @FXML
    private void actionStart(ActionEvent event) {  
        String path = "C:\\root\\";
        directory = new File(path);    

        myProzessBar.progressProperty().unbind();        
        myProzessBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

    }
```

I'm trying for several days to solve the and now I have no more idea.

please help me.

Comment: What do you want to combine? And how do your update methods look like?

Comment: Where is `task` declared and initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
private Path directory;

.....        
private Task<ObservableList<Integer>> createWorker() {

    return new Task<ObservableList<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        protected ObservableList<Integer> call() throws Exception {
            Stack<Path> stack = new Stack();
            stack.push(directory);
            int i = 0;
            while (!stack.empty()) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
                Path root = stack.pop();
                try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(root);) {
                    for (Path path : stream) {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                            stack.push(path);
                        } else {

                            if (path.toString().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                                i++;
                                results.add(i);
                                updateProgress(i, 100);
                                updateValue(results);
                                Thread.sleep(5);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }

            }
            return results;
        }

    };

}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I wanted, it works perfectly, I think I could not have done, without you. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

With this i can read the rootfolder, but not the subfolders.
That's easy.

But i must can read the rootfolder and the subfolder's.

Here is the Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.concurrent.WorkerStateEvent;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button startButton;
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar myProzessBar;
    @FXML
    private Label label;


private Task<Boolean> myWorker;
private int countPDF;
private File directory;

@FXML
private void actionStart(ActionEvent event) {  
    String path = "C:\\root\\";
    directory = new File(path);
    if(!directory.isDirectory())
        return;
    countPDF = 0;
    myWorker = createWorker(directory);
    myWorker.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            startButton.setDisable(false);
            label.textProperty().unbind();
            label.setText("Total " + countPDF);
        }
    });
    myProzessBar.progressProperty().unbind();
    myProzessBar.progressProperty().bind(myWorker.progressProperty());
    label.textProperty().bind(myWorker.messageProperty());
    new Thread(myWorker).start();
    startButton.setDisable(true);
}

@FXML
void initialize() {

}

private Task<Boolean> createWorker(File fileRoot) {    
    return new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {

            File[] files = fileRoot.listFiles();
            for(File file : files) {
                if(file.isDirectory())
                // restart the method, but how can I do that
                else{
                    String fileName = file.getName();
                    if(fileName.endsWith(".pdf")){
                        updateMessage(++countPDF + "");
                        updateProgress(countPDF, 100);

                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
}
```